# JQueryUI datepicker onSelect always bring the first object

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a HTML table where one of the columns has a text input. I need to attach a datepicker widget to each of the inputs. I'm using the folowing code to achieve this (each input has a "dateInput" css class):

```
$(".dateInput").datepicker({ onSelect: dateInput_select });
```

As shown, I'm also using the onSelect event, because there is some things i must do when the user selects a date.

```
function dateInput_select(date, obj) 
{

}
```

The problem is, when the onSelect event is fired, the obj parameter is always the first input control in the table, regardless of wich row i use.

How can i access the correct control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was posting this question when i had a idea that might solve the problem, and it really solved. I decided to post the question anyway, so it could help someone with the same problem.

The problem was that input controls had all the same ID. When i changed my creation logic so each control has a different name, everything worked fine.